# embed multiple twitter users' timeline HTML

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Hi I want to embed a twitter timeline into my website but I cannot figure out how to do it.
Basically, in twitter, I'm following multiple users and whenever the users tweet something, I want their tweets to show in my embedded timeline in real time.

p.s. It doesn't matter if I have to use javascript or other languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

May be this is what you are looking for;

Create a list on twitter then add members to this list and then finally create a Widgets to get embed code for this list;

[How to embed a timeline](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170071)

Comment: is there a way that I don't need to add members but automatically adds all the members that I am following into the widget?

Comment: Not sure but you can do this bulk addition with api calls.

Comment: could you tell me how to do it

Comment: @H.Kim Have a look on this [Adds multiple members to a list](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/lists/members/create_all).